# Dynamic Keyed Each?

Tags: svelte

Can [keyed each blocks](https://svelte.technology/guide#keyed-each-blocks) have a dynamic key, using the value of a component property?

For example:

```
{{#each items as item @{componentPropertyExpression}}}
    <div>{{item.stuff}}</div>
{{/each}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not currently — there's a discussion around it though: https://github.com/sveltejs/svelte/issues/703

Answer (score 3):

Just in case anyone lands over this question, since Svelte v2.4.0 (Apr 2018), you can have dynamic expression for your keyed each block:

```
{#each list as item (item.id)}
  <li>{item.name}</li>
{/each}
```

Check out the official tutorial: https://svelte.dev/tutorial/keyed-each-blocks

And if you learn better with videos, check out https://youtu.be/kN4R29zbh7g and https://youtu.be/itcf8S8Az74

Comment: You can also apply the same “keyed” concept to a single block using the new `{#key myKey}…{/key}` block [doc here](https://svelte.dev/docs#key). BTW, the feature is implemented by this guywho seems too humble to plug even it’s obviously related. Kudos man   